# Remove inline CSS in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

This inline CSS is generated by jssor-slider,

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
width: 1500px;
height: 700px; 
transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; 
transform: scale(0.876644);
```

and I want to override it with,

```
position: absolute; 
top: 0px; 
left: 0px; 
width: 100%; 
height: 700px;
```

I tried it by the following,

```
$('#slider_container').width('100%');
$('#slider_container > div').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px', 'left':' 0px', 'width':' 10%', 'height':' 700px'});
```

I was successful, but this always remain.

```
transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; 
transform: scale(0.876644);
```

How to remove this using jQuery?

Comment: When you say "inline css", do you mean that this is within `<style></style>` tags, or that it's within a `style` attribute on an html element?

Comment: Its like <div style="css here" >..

Comment: you could flush the data in the style attribute first, then add what you need `$('#slider_container').attr('style', '')` [Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexisdiamondhotmailca/mwjonmjw/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the `transform` back to its default value. Which for `transform` is `scale(1)`, and for `transform-origin` is `50% 50% 0`.

**jQuery**

```
$('#slider_container > div').css({'transform': 'scale(1)', 'transform-origin': '50% 50% 0'});
```

**[JSFiddle (Before)](https://jsfiddle.net/qevbx4og/1/)**

**[JSFiddle (After)](https://jsfiddle.net/qevbx4og/)**

***Note** This solution is acceptable if the styles are defined from a stylesheet. Otherwise, if they are defined inline (which was recently clarified by the OP), then Rudi Urbanek's solution would be ideal.

```
$('#slider_container > div').removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

an easy solution is to first remove the inline style attribute before adding your new style.

```
$('#slider_container > div').removeAttr("style");
$('#slider_container > div').css({'position': 'absolute', 'top': '0px', 'left':' 0px', 'width':' 10%', 'height':' 700px'});
```